# Salesforce Query to Check the Existing Contact with Account id

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-ios-sdk, salesforce-communities

I already have contact by using *Accountid*, so before creating the new contact I want to verify the existing contact with email and id, can you please help me with this salesforce query to check if the Contact already exist with Contact *Email* and *AccountId*?

I already tried using the below query but it was throwing exceptions:

```html
SELECT Id, Name , email 
FROM Contact
WHERE email='XXX@Email.com'
AND Id IN (SELECT ContactId
   FROM AccountContactRelation
   WHERE AccountId = 'XXXX')
```

Got the below error:

> INVALID_TYPE:  and Id IN (SELECT ContactId FROM AccountContactRelation
>   WHERE AccountId
>                                    ^
>
> ERROR at Row:1:Column:121 sObject type 'AccountContactRelation' is not
>   supported. If you are attempting to use a custom object, be sure to
>   append the '__c' after the entity name. Please reference your WSDL or
>   the describe call for the appropriate names.

Can you please share the correct Salesforce Query ?

Answer (score 0):

The below Query worked like charm :)

```
SELECT Id, Name , email 
FROM Contact 
WHERE email='XXXXXXXXX@XXX.com' 
      AND AccountId='YYYYY@yyy.com'
```